# Node JS: How to Extract data from a Web Site that uses JavaScript functions to Load the data

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, web-scraping

I'm using Node JS with Nick JS (Chromium) to crawl a website. When I reach my destination page there are a few JavaScript functions that expose additional data that I want to Extract.

The problem I'm having is when I save the HTML to file, the data displayed from the JavaScript functions doesn't exist (obviously). My question is, how can I properly extract this data?

I've tried working with the DOM and I think that might be the right way to go but I'm not sure...

Comment: Take a look at [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/). I've never used it but it's recommend to web scrape dynamic web pages along with some other plugins I don't remember right now

Comment: phantomjs is more or less dying, either go with puppeteer or jsdom + scripts execution if you know what you're doing